# Regular expression behaving different on in c# code behind and on aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

Note: question has been edited to stay in sync with what I have tried from the commenters

I am trying to match an email, however when put the same expression in the code behind, vs the aspx, I seem to be getting different matches for email address. The aspx regex validator seems to be working correctly, however I need to validate for my webservice as well. Im sure Im missing something simple here, does anyone have any ideas.

```
 Regex regExEmail = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"); 
 if (!regExEmail.IsMatch(contact.emailAddress))
 {
     //do something
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't "^(\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*$" be enough?  (Sorry for the non-answer)  Edit:  Nevermind :)

Comment: I believe we are using the standard microsoft email validation regex.

Comment: Do you have an example of something it matches incorrectly in one case, but not the other?

Comment: This regex doesn't look right to me. You need to escape the periods: @"^(\w+([-+\.]\w+)*@\w+([-\.]\w+)*\.\w+([-\.]\w+)*)$"

Comment: thanks, here is what I have done. I have changed the regex to :“\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*”. On the regulax expression on the aspx side it will not validate “abc.efg@xyz@abc@eee.com”. however on the cs validator like I have above, it will. What is the difference between the validators. I can probably figure out how to make it work on the cs side by using a different expression, though that is not the point, why are these things behaving differently. By the way, thanks so much to everyone that is helping, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Regex constructor, you can use the two-parameter version to set the RegexOptions value. This enumeration includes a value for ECMAScript, which will cause the Regex matching to follow ECMAScript-compliant behavior.

Comment: This would help if the goal is to get a JavaScript regexp and ASP.NET regexp to work the same way, but I'm not sure how it helps here.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - I took the OP's question to mean that his rendered ASP.NET page (hence HTML/JavaScript) was using the specified regex, and he wanted his web service to use the same regex for validation. Setting the ECMAScript enum in the regex constructor used by the web service should accomplish this, correct?

Comment: Yes JeremyDWill, that is exactly what I was trying to say. I apologize if I did not word my question correctly

Answer (score 1):

Use `asp:CustomValidator` instead of RegularExpressionValidator which will call any validation method from a library, the same as will be used by the WS.